# How to use iOS with Robot Framework in Plone

Tags: plone, robotframework, travis-ci, saucelabs

I'm writing Robot Framework tests for a Plone project.

Here is [the code](https://github.com/toutpt/plonetheme.jquerymobile).

I want tests to be executed on Sauce Labs, but with two different OS's:

- iOS
- Android

I'm starting by replacing the current default tests (Firefox / WinXP) with iOS, using the following parameters in my .travis.yml's matrix:

```
  - TARGET=test ROBOT_DESIRED_CAPABILITIES="platform:OS X 10.8,browserName:iPad,version:6,tunnel-identifier:$TRAVIS_JOB_ID"
```

Tests are now failing with the following issues:

```
 Could not proxy http://localhost:3001/wd/hub/session, exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

I have no idea why. I have read all the stuff in example.product and I didn't find any differences.

Here are [my builds](https://travis-ci.org/toutpt/plonetheme.jquerymobile/jobs/7948667) at Travis CI, which show the errors.

And you can find my Sauce Labs results [here](https://saucelabs.com/u/plonetheme-jquerymob).

[image: Sauce Labs test results]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, you have to run your test ZServer (by settings ZSERVER_PORT environment variable) at some port supported by Sauce Labs: https://saucelabs.com/docs/connect#localhost

- I have a working example at: https://github.com/datakurre/example.product
- I filed a request for SauceLabs to add support for port 55001 used by Plone, and the port will be included in the next SauceConnect-release.

**Update:** There was an another issue. p.a.robotframework defines Selenium version for Sauce Labs, currently 2.31.0 (UPDATE: next release will not set the default value). I asked this from Sauce Labs and it seems that selenium version should not be set for mobile tests at all.

- I have now a working p.a.robotframework example at: https://github.com/datakurre/example.product/tree/p.a.robotframework
- To reset Sauce Labs Selenium version set by p.a.robotframework, you could set an environment variable `ROBOT_SELENIUM_VERSION=" "` for mobile Travis builds as in https://github.com/datakurre/example.product/commit/4deafc843b89a66da8cf6a85955a2b936ada79b4

*Technically `ROBOT_SELENIUM_VERSION=""` should be enough for p.a.robotframework to use the default Selenium version of Sauce Labs, but when I tested that in `.travis.yml`, Travis didn't set that environment variable at all and it didn't override p.a.robotframework's default. Anyway, the next p.a.robotframework-release (>= 0.6.2) will set no selenium-version for Sauce Labs by default.*

**Background**:

- Sauce Labs documentation related to Selenium version: https://saucelabs.com/docs/additional-config#selenium-version
- p.a.robotframework code for defining `SELENIUM_VERSION`-variable for Robot Framework and forcing `selenium-version` Selenium desired capabilities string for Sauce Labs: https://github.com/plone/plone.app.robotframework/blob/master/src/plone/app/robotframework/saucelabs.robot#L25
- Finally `robotsuite`, which is used used to wrap Robot Framework tests for `zope.testrunner`, passes all `ROBOT_`-prefixed environment variables for Robot Framework test runner without the prefix, effectively overriding the default set in p.a.robotframework.

Comment: Your example work but you do not use plone.app.robotframework (nothing is imported in the **setup**. Lots of stuff seems outdated (like testing.Keywords which is a copy/paste of plone.app.robotframework.saucelabs.Saucelabs)

And I don't understand why it should work with FF on winxp and not ios.

Comment: Ok. I'll make a robotframework branch for that example tomorrow. (Actually, I did the copy & paste other way around...). I don't know either, why desktop browser work with port 55001, but emulators only with officially forwarded ports.

Comment: thanks. If I compare your travis log and mine your use GET request on 8080 where mine use POST on 3001. https://travis-ci.org/toutpt/plonetheme.jquerymobile/jobs/7956789 && https://travis-ci.org/datakurre/example.product/jobs/7293370